# How to update primary key table based on foreign key with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `users` table with autoincrement `id` as primary key, and a unique key on `email`. The `email` and `name` fields are from Facebook.

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | email | name |
+----+-------+------+
```

And a `facebook_users` table,

```
+--------+----------+
| userId | fbUserId |
+--------+----------+
```

The `id` is a foreign key to `userId` on the Facebook table. The `fbUserId` is guaranteed to be unique by Facebook. The reason I split these tables up is I plan to have more social logins in the future, and I'm trying to make my schema future proof.

Right now my insert update query is this

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO users 
    (id,email,name) 
    VALUES (0,?,?);

    INSERT IGNORE INTO users_facebook
    (userId, fbUserId)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?);
COMMIT
```

From what I understand, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` only applies to a single row in a single table.

What I'd like to do is if one of my existing users (meaning I have their `fbUserId` in my database) changes their `email` or `name` on Facebook, I'd like to update the `users` table.

The way I'm doing it now seems.. "backward"? Because `fbUserId` is the "real" primary key, but I'm trying to insert into `users` first.

Also, any thoughts on my current query? I'm quite new to MySQL.

**EDIT**: I ended up moving email to facebook table and using a stored procedure.

- `users` table is `id, name` ;
- `facebook_users` table is `userId, email, fbUserId`;

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'facebook_user_login'(
    firstName varchar(50),
    lastName varchar(50),
    email varchar(50),
    fbUserId bigint(8)
)
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (select * from users_facebook a where a.fbUserId = fbUserId) THEN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO users values (0,'eric','guan');
        INSERT INTO users_facebook values (LAST_INSERT_ID(),email, fbUserId);
    END;
    ELSEIF EXISTS (select * from users_facebook a where a.fbUserId = fbUserId and a.email != email ) THEN
    UPDATE users_facebook set email = email;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: I only see one email field.  Can you better describe the situation?

Comment: Say i have `56, bob@gmail.com, bob` in `users`. and then `56, 4534` in `facebook_users`. Bob then changes his facebook email to `boblaw@gmail.com`. He logs into my app and i authenticate him thru facebook. Facebook gives me his `fbUserId` which is still `4534` and also his new email. Once I try to `INSERT IGNORE` bob into the `users` table, how can i detect that his `fbUserId` of `4534` exists in `facebook_users`, therefore I know he's an existing user, and i need to update his email?

Comment: I see a problem here with your design.  What if a given user in your system has both Facebook and Google credentials, and what if the emails don't match?  The direct answer to your question, assuming you really only have Facebook as a provider, would be to just overwrite the old email address, assuming you take Facebook's latest info as being authoritative.  But again, if you also have other providers, this could get messy.

Comment: Yeah i think i'm seeing the problem too. I think i need to store an email per social login account, and maybe let the user choose which one is the "main" email. Which i would then store in the `users` table.

Comment: If you use OAuth for this, which you most likely would, then you could also cache an access token for each provider, for each user.